# Call an anonymous function within a custom function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I want to call an anonymous function in a custom MATLAB function. From the script that calls the custom function, I want to minimize the custom MATLAB function. I am having a problem with the anonymous function not being passed correctly to the function.

As a MWE, I have a script, in which I define an anonymous function, `afunction`,

```matlab
% directory for minimization algorithm
addpath '/somedirectory/FMINSEARCHBND'

% anonymous function
afunction = @(x) x.^2 + 2.*x - 71;

% 1D minimization guesses
xguess = 20;
xmin = -1000;
xmax = 1000;

% 1D minimization call
minx = fminsearchbnd(@(x) MWEtestfuntominimize(x), xguess, xmin, xmax);
```

I then have a custom function written in another file `MWEtestfuntominimize`,

```
function g = MWEtestfuntominimize(x)
    g = abs(afunction(x));
end
```

I expect my main script to minimize `MWEtestfuntominimize`, but it seems that `MWEtestfuntominimize` cannot call `afunction`. The error message is

```
Undefined function or variable 'afunction'
```

I have tried passing `afunction` through `MWEtestfuntominimize` as an argument, which was unsuccessful. This was through modifying `minx` in the minimization call as

```
minx = fminsearchbnd(@(afunction,x) MWEtestfuntominimize(afunction,x), xguess, xmin, xmax);
```

and modifying the custom function to

```
function g = MWEtestfuntominimize(afunction,x)
    g = abs(afunction(x));
end
```

The resulting error was

```
"afunction" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
```

I know a solution would be to define the anonymous function in `MWEtestfuntominimize` itself, but for the specific program I am writing, I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that passing `afunction` "was unsuccessful" but didn't show why... that's exactly how I'd solve this issue

```
% anonymous function
afunction = @(x) x.^2 + 2.*x - 71;
% 1D minimization call
minx = fminsearchbnd(@(x) MWEtestfuntominimize(x, afunction), xguess, xmin, xmax);
```

Then inside your minimization function...

```
function g = MWEtestfuntominimize(x, fcn)
    g = abs( fcn(x) );
end
```

To expand on why this works, `fminsearchbnd` expects a function with a single input. This is a function with only one input (`x`)

```
@(x) MWEtestfuntominimize( x, afunction )
```

The function handle (or other variable) `afunction` is stored within the anonymous function, with the same value within the workspace at that point. Note that if `afunction` changes afterwards, it will **not** change within your anonymous function.

A simple example would be

```
a = 2;
f = @(x) x + a;

f(5); % = 7

a = 4; % change 'a' after the definition of 'f'
f(5); % = 7, does not change as f = @(x) x + 2 still
```

Comment: This works, but why is the argument of fminsearchbnd only `@(x)`, and not `@(afunction,x)`?